# Can the Apple Pencil (2nd gen) be endowed with a pointer on screen for the iPad pro (3rd gen)?

Tags: ipad, apple-pencil

I know Bluetooth mice can get a pointer going in Accessibility > Touch > Assistive Touch > Pointer Devices.

It would be good (my use case is online teaching, where I would like to be able to point things) if the Apple Pencil could benefit from the same pointer on hovering, but when I scan for BT devices the pencil doesn't appear, making me think it probably is not compatible.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Pointer displays are for things that don't interact with the screen, like mice and trackpads. The pencil directly contacts the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Pencil cannot act as a pointer device.

> Plug in your wired mouse, trackpad or Bluetooth device using a Lightning or USB-C port.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT210546

There’s no APIs for detecting hovering so you won’t find the functionality in any third-party apps either.

> UIKit reports touches from Apple Pencil

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_input_from_apple_pencil